# Why won't this DELETE query work?

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why this query won't work. I did a SELECT to verify it's pulling the rows that I want.  I put in DELETE and now it won't work.

Here is my SELECT query:

```
SELECT dh.dragon_list_id, dh.habitat_list_id 
FROM dragon_to_habitat dh, dragon_list dl
  WHERE dh.dragon_list_id = dl.dragon_list_id
    AND dl.user_id = 1
    AND dl.is_deleted = false
```

I'm sure it's something stupid I'm overlooking.  Little help is appreciated.

```
DELETE FROM dragon_to_habitat dh
  WHERE dh.dragon_list_id = dragon_list.dragon_list_id
    AND dragon_list.user_id = 1
    AND dragon_list.is_deleted = false
```

I also tried this query with a JOIN that did not work:

```
DELETE 
FROM dragon_to_habitat as dh JOIN 
     dragon_list as dl ON dh.dragon_list_id = dl.dragon_list_id
WHERE dl.user_id = 1 AND dl.is_deleted = false
```

Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as dh JOIN dragon_list as dl ON dh.dragon_list_id = dl.dragon_list_id WH' at line 2

I only want to clear the values in the dragon_to_habitat table.  The dragon_list table should be untouched.

For good measure, here's my schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ac6a1

Comment: wont work? can provide select query too?

Comment: What is your error message? Also, I see that you are using dragon_list but i don't see any joins

Comment: What is `dragon_list`? Another table?

Comment: don't you have to use a join if using more than 1 table?

Comment: Your table name is `dragon_to_habitat dh` It can not have a space in it, it must be a typo.

Comment: @Vector It's not a typo, it's assigning an alias to the table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN`the `dragon_to_habitat`and `dragon_list` table -

```
DELETE FROM dragon_to_habitat AS dh
JOIN dragon_list AS dragon_list ON dh.dragon_list_id = dragon_list.dragon_list_id
WHERE dragon_list.user_id = 1 AND dragon_list.is_deleted = false
```

Comment: Didn't work, tried a JOIN.  I added to the original question the query and error.

Comment: Use this -




DELETE dh FROM dragon_to_habitat AS dh INNER JOIN dragon_list AS dl ON dh.dragon_list_id = dl.dragon_list_id WHERE dl.user_id =1 AND dl.is_deleted =0

One more thing in where condition you have used dragon_list.is_deleted = false but the type for is_deleted is tinyint, you need to change that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JOIN`:

```
DELETE 
FROM dragon_to_habitat as dh JOIN 
     dragon_list as dl ON dh.dragon_list_id = dl.id
WHERE dl.user_id = 1 AND dl.is_deleted = false
```

Comment: Didn't work, tried a JOIN.  I added to the original question the query and error.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM 
 dragon_to_habitat 
USING 
  dragon_to_habitat dh 
INNER JOIN 
  dragon_list dl 
ON 
  dh.dragon_list_id = dl.dragon_list_id 
AND 
  dl.user_id = 1 
AND 
  dl.is_deleted = false
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.